# ArcGIS Online heatmap

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online, heat-map, excel

ArcGIS 10.2, ESRI Maps for MS Office
Why a heatmap that was created in Excel and looks fine and is still fine on a preview of a map if I publish it it ArcGIS Online  but turns into black points if I open it in ArcGIS Online map viewer ?

[image: It is what I like]
[image: It's What I have]

Comment: Are you publishing a vector or raster format?

Comment: I only choose "To publish" in Excel and that's all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The ESRI Maps for Office help references this:

> Heat map layers and layers that are clustered cannot be shared to ArcGIS Online as a layer, but can be shared as part of a map. In the ArcGIS.com Map Viewer, the heat map layer displays as a point layer instead of rendering as a heat map.

[Source](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/esri-maps-office/index.html#//02930000000v000000)